# display events in week view fullcalender

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

[image]

Here am displaying events in fullcalender.

But coming to Week view the events r not displaying in events time.

Here testing event timings are 10:00 AM to 12:00 PM. but the event is showing at top level.

```
function DisplayCalendar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{}",
        url: "Events.aspx/GetEvents",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            $('div[id*=calendar]').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                select: selectDate,
                eventClick: updateEvent,
                editable: true,
                droppable: false,
                draggable: false,
                disableDragging: true,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                eventTextColor: 'Yellow',
                eventBackgroundColor: 'purple',
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                    if (view.name == 'agendaWeek') {
                        //alert(view.visStart);
                    }
                    //return false;
                },
                events: $.map(data.d, function(item, i) {
                    var sdate = item.StartDate;
                    var sdatesplit = sdate.split("/");
                    var sm = sdatesplit[0];
                    var sd = sdatesplit[1];
                    var sy = sdatesplit[2];
                    var syearsplit = sy.split(" ");

                    var edate = item.EndDate;
                    var edatesplit = edate.split("/");
                    var em = edatesplit[0];
                    var ed = edatesplit[1];
                    var ey = edatesplit[2];
                    var eyearsplit = ey.split(" ");
                    var event = new Object();
                    event.id = item.EventID;
                    event.start = new Date(syearsplit[0], sm, sd, 16, 0);
                    event.end = new Date(eyearsplit[0], em, ed, 18, 0);
                    event.title = item.EventName;
                    event.allDay = true;
                    return event;
                    //event.id= item.EventID;
                    //event.title= item.EventName;
                    //event.start= new Date(y, m, d, 16, 0);
                    //event.end= new Date(y, m, d, 16, 30);
                    //event.allDay= true;
                    //return event;
                })
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
        }
});
```

Comment: hi am attached the code just c

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar shows you events in top, because you set "allDay" property for event:

```
event.allDay = true;
```

Check [fullcalendar documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) for allDay property:

> Also, in the agenda views, determines if it is displayed in the "all-day" section.